# http.ServeFile can not get the static sources, but command run can get

Tags: go, intellij-idea, build, command, intellij-14

I use the Intelj IDEA to develop golang, but when I use the debug to build my project, when debug to this line `http.ServeFile(w, r, "./static/html/login.html")`, I get `404 not found`, but in command run, I can get this static page.

Answer (score 0):

The path `"./static/html/login.html"` is a relative path. When you utilize `go run ...` you are probably currently in a directory that this relative path resolves to correctly. The IntelliJ binary may be executed in a different directory than your go source resulting this relative path being incorrect.

You can either use an absolute path in your call to `ServeFile(...)`, configure your IDE to execute your go commands in the source directory as the working directory, or allow your application to be configured to use any given path as the root of your static content. The first two options will temporarily solve your problem. When you have to ship your binary it will be susceptible to the same problem you're experiencing now. The third option will allow your application to handle any environment because the path can be explicitly defined by the user.